# Fullscreen website with horizontal overflow scroll on 100% width

Tags: width, fullscreen, horizontal-scrolling, css

I have one problem with my code and I can't find a solution. 
I have left sidebar w: 300px h:100% , and I want the right div (content area) to be w: 100% and h:100% with horizontal scrollbar..

But something is wrong in my code and I cannot figure out, the right div is going over the side bar, and if I put margin-left:300px, then they 300px are added on those 100px weight.

I hope you understand me, here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <?php include '../side_bar.php' ?>

    <div id="content">
       <div id="scroll">
        <img src="../images/design1.jpg" width="759" height="565"> 
        <img src="../images/design1.jpg" width="759" height="565"> 
        <img src="../images/design1.jpg" width="759" height="565"> 
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}

#side_bar {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    border-right:#000 solid 1px;
}

#content {
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
}

#scroll {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;  
    white-space: nowrap; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the functionality you wanted with the following tweaked CSS:

```
body, html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
#wrapper {
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:inline-block;
}

#side_bar {
/*float:left;*/
top:0;
left:0;
width:300px;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
border-right:#000 solid 1px;
background-color:#333;
}

#content {
/*float:left;*/
top:0;
left:0;
height:100%;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
}

#scroll {
height:100%;
/*width:100%;*/
right:0px;
left:301px; /*Because of border */
display:inline-block;
position:absolute;
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-y:hidden;  
white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a full screen website by using [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) plugin for jQuery:

- [Demo](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)
- [Github account](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)

It provide not only a way to create vertical sections but also horizontal ones.

Some pros:

- Auto scrolling moving the mouse wheel
- Use of anchors(#) in the URL
- Compatible with touch devices
- Compatible with old browsers (> IE7)
- Provides callbacks and lots of useful functions
- Strongly tested in different devices